# Google Map API v2 - Set padding not taking into account when moveCamera

Tags: android, google-maps

Info window is drawn out of map so I decided to add padding to the map. The camera position well according to padding when i tap on marker but failed to achieve the same effect using moveCamera function. It seems like moveCamera function doesn't take padding into account or I did it wrongly? Please advise. Thanks.

```
mGoogleMap.setPadding(0,140,0,0);

Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointer))
            .title("Crime happened here!")
            .snippet("(" + roundFourDecimals(latLng.latitude) + "," + roundFourDecimals(latLng.longitude) + ")"));
    marker.showInfoWindow();

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(17).build()));
```

Comment: put mGoogleMap.setPadding(0,140,0,0); again after moveCamera()

Comment: @ChiragSavsani not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have altered the code by moving camera to your desire LatLng, then use VisibleRegion and LatLngBounds to get the center of the visible region. Works like charm.

**Be sure to do this in onMapLoadedCallback to prevent nullpointerexception as it requires the height and width of the map fragment**

```
  mGoogleMap.setPadding(0,140,0,0);

  Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getCrimeIcon(crimeType)))
            .title("Crime happened here!")
            .snippet("(" + roundFourDecimals(latLng.latitude) + "," + roundFourDecimals(latLng.longitude) + ")"));
    marker.showInfoWindow();

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,17));

    VisibleRegion visibleRegion = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    LatLngBounds mapLatLngBound = visibleRegion.latLngBounds;

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mapLatLngBound.getCenter()));
```